# Issue with at job called via cron (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

Calling the job with at fails using a different timezone

We have the following scenario. All servers are running in UTC.
We have a bunch of clients in the US and an application config determines a job to run in EST. (This means that the job time changes relative to UTC for daylight savings changes, ie job runs at same local time).
The issue we have is that we need to call another job from cron that runs an hour before the application job.
This new job checks the date and if the day portion matches a given value, it runs the rest of the code and exits if not.
(For the purposes of the test, today is the 11th)

Here's a script (BASH) snippet:

```sh
TODAY=$(date +%d)
echo ${TODAY}
if [[ "${TODAY}" == "11" ]]
then
echo "Today is last day of month" 
# run my job
else
echo "Today is not last day of month" 
fi
```

To complicate things we have the following in our crontab:

```
TZ='America/New_York'
```

When I run the script from the console, log entry as follows:

```
11
Today is last day of month (as expected)
```

When I schedule the script from cron as follows:

```
46 11 * * *  /opt/mytest.sh
```

The job runs at 11:46 UTC with log output as follows:

```
11
Today is last day of month (as expected)
```

When I schedule the script from cron as follows:

```
50 11 * * * at -f /opt/mytest.sh 07:51 (invoke at job to run at 7:51 est, ie 1151 utc)
```

The job writes to log at 11:51 utc, but the log entry is as follows:

```
11
Today is not last day of month (not my expected result)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The first log line is `echo $TODAY`?

Comment: What's the difference between `mytest.sh` and `fintest.sh`?

Comment: The best way to debug shell scripts is to put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. Then it will log a transcript of all the commands, with variables expanded.

Comment: Sorry, yes. First line is echo $TODAY, and filename changed for consistency.

Comment: `at` is probably running the script with `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`. Get rid of all the `bash` extensions in the script, such as `[[` and `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a number of `bash` extensions in the script. `at` uses the value of `$SHELL` to determine which shell to execute the script with, and it's probably defaulting to `/bin/sh` in `cron`. So set the environment variable appropriately:

```
50 11 * * * SHELL=/bin/bash at -f /opt/mytest.sh 07:51 (invoke at job to run at 7:51 est, ie 1151 utc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Still no joy, both using the SHELL= in crontab and modifying script to remove bash extensions. (Have invoked /bin/sh and run script successfully from command line)

Comment: What did you learn by putting `set -x` in the script to debug it?

Comment: Sorted, using [ ] instead of [[ ]] and = instead of ==. Thanks so much for your help. One question: I originally had #!/bin/bash in the script for testing. Do you know why at would ignore this?

Comment: Those are the bash extensions I was talking about.